# How to get values with a different "path" in the database?

Tags: python, django

I want to get values from a table (the end goal is to create a dataframe out of a queryset). Those values depend on a form submitted by a user. Here is a simplified snippet of my models:

```py
class Report_Sample(models.Model):
    assay = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    samtools_data = models.ForeignKey(
        "Samtools_data", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True
    )
    picard = models.ForeignKey(
        "Picard", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True

class Samtools_data(models.Model):
    total_passed = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    total_failed = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Picard(models.Model):
    sample = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    library = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    read_group = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    picard_hs_metrics = models.ForeignKey(
        "Picard_hs_metrics", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True
    )

class Picard_hs_metrics(models.Model):
    bait_set = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bait_territory = models.FloatField()
```

Using the form, the user can select a subset of `Report_sample` objects and a metric to look at.

So let's say the user wants the Samtools `total_passed` field. I can do:

```py
subset_report_samples = Report_sample.objects.filter(whatever_filter_the_user_wanted)

metric_filter = None

for model in apps.get_models():
    for field in model._meta.get_fields():
        if field.name == metric:
            metric_filter = f"{model.__name__.lower()}__{metric}"
            break

subset_report_samples.objects.values(metric_filter)
```

If we want to access the `Picard_hs_metrics` table however this breaks because of the intermediary table `Picard`. I thought about using a try/except block using `from django.core.exceptions import FieldError` but it feels horrible to use.

So i was wondering if there was a Django method to find that `metric_filter` string given the field of a model.

Answer (score 0):

right now my solution is the following:

```
    # handle cases where there is an intermediary table between Report sample
    # and the table containing the metric field
    for intermediate_table in ["", "picard"]:
        if intermediate_table != "":
            # add the intermediary table in the filter string
            metric_filter = f"{intermediate_table}__{metric_filter}"

        try:
            Report_Sample.objects.all().values(metric_filter)
        # the filter failed i.e. couldn't access the metric field using the
        # built filter from Report_sample
        except FieldError:
            continue
        else:
            return metric_filter
```